# Customization of Tapku Calendar for iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, tapku

Any one can give me quick idea to convert the tapku library calendar for iPad bigger screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've converted the tapku library calendar for iPad bigger screen.you can download it from the following repository.
https://github.com/dhinesh03/tapkulibrary .

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the entire calendar bigger to fit iPad screen? I think that is too big for normal users (except old user). My suggest is make split view then implement the calendar into the master view(on the left), below it you should display details of current selected day in a tableview. And the detail view(on the right) will act like an "detail view"  when you select a row in the tableview. Hope this idea help.

In case, you still want to make the calendar as big as screen. You can access to TapkuLibrary.xcodeproj and change size of calendar( you must look through the files- I forgot exactly where i changed it, just remember changed size in few lines of code). And then you have to create new images for day cells and others to fix to new size.